# Is the processing time on emulator more than than on a real device?(android, eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, optimization, emulation

I am making an android app. When I run it on the emulator, which has 512 MiB RAM, a simple activity takes 3 seconds to complete. Will this time be lower on a real device, as 3 seconds is inacceptably long! If it will be lower then by what factor( an estimate will do)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on exactly what you're doing, but as a rule of the thumb, devices are much faster than emulators.

Emulators are slow because an entire ARM process architecture is emulated through software, which adds a (big) extra layer between the Android system and your computer's processor.

Trying using one of the x86 intel images for a faster emulator closer to device speeds.

However, no emulator will give you the same speed as a device.

Comment: So 3 seconds on the emulator will reduce to how much approximately on a real device?

Comment: @ankitrawat You can't really predict it. It depends on the device and task.

Comment: Ok. But, is 3 seconds normal? Other light activities take half a second or so to complete. Do I need to optimize my code for this particular activity?

Comment: @ankitrawat You haven't even told us what you do in the Activity, so I can't say.

Comment: It reads 3200 lines from a 50 kb .txt file and stores them in an array. Then it searches the array and saves around 60 lines in another array, based on some criteria. Then I use listview to put the lines from the 2nd array into a list. This is what it does.